# How to inherit sorting view from filter menu in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to apply filter from DATA -> Create Filter in Google Sheet and when I have e.g. 10 items in specific table I want to have only 10 rows (delete other empty rows) and when I apply that filter for specific column It creates me a fully working filtering and sorting column. After that when I add some new item dynamically using Glide App for making App from google sheet project It adds me new row (number 11) but without filter and sort range.

View after creating filter:

[image]

After add new item from Glide app:

[image]

That newly incoming item doesn't inherit that sorting and filtering view. Is there any way to force that inheritance? I cannot set via google sheet range B3:B by using filter I can only mark range and I have set whole column B when I was creating that filter.

It is possible to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: You could create a time-driven trigger with Google Apps Script which would periodically (every minute would be highest possible frequency) update the filter based on current sheet content. Do you think that could be a valid workaround for you? If that's the case, I'd consider posting an answer with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Sounds as best possible solution for now

Comment: All right, could you please provide more details about what kind of sorting and filtering have you set up, in order to provide the corresponding Apps Script code?

Comment: Simply filter from google sheet data menu. I marked up whole column and I have set Data -> Create a Filter. That's all

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer regarding this, could you confirm whether that works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue and workaround:

Since the data is getting appended programmatically by a third-party, there is no way to automatically update the filter to include the new data.

As a workaround, you can install an Apps Script [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) in order to update the filter periodically (taking into account the different [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder), the highest possible frequency is one minute), according to current data.

Of course, it would be more appropriate to trigger the update immediately after data is added, but unfortunately, triggers like [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) only work for changes made by users.

#### Function to update filter:

First, create a function that will update the filter. Select `Tools > Script editor` to open a [script bound to your spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), copy the following function and save the project:

```
function updateFilter() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Sheet name (change if necessary)
  var filterColumn = 2; // Column index (change if necessary)
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var filter = sheet.getFilter();
  if (filter) filter.remove(); // Remove previous filter if it exists
  sheet.getRange(1, filterColumn, sheet.getLastRow()).createFilter();
}
```

This function removes the current filter (if it exists), and creates a new one at column B of a sheet named `Sheet1` (please change these according to your preferences).

#### Install time-driven trigger:

Then, you would need to install the time-trigger so that the previous function executes every minute. This can be installed manually, by following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually), or programmatically, by running [this function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyminutesn) once:

```
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("updateFilter")
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(1)
    .create();
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Class ClockTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)

Comment: Yes, thank you for answer :) Sorry for late I was busy